# One word for travelling job

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the profession that involves frequent traveling

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: Why was the answer deleted, it seems fine to me.

Comment: Is the travelling intrinsic to his job e.g. truck driver, or does it mean the person takes different means of transport because his/her job involves travelling around the country and overseas? Or is it do with commuting? Please, add some more detail.

Comment: More context is needed for an answer that isn't based chiefly on an implausible ability to read your mind.

Comment: @Kris, after posting my answer, I re-read the question and got confused about what the OP was looking for.  I think it was too late in the night for me to think straight.  I will undelete it.

Comment: related:[Word for annoying travel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211430/word-for-annoying-travel)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of professions that involve frequent traveling.  If you are looking for a generic term, then **road warrior** fits the bill.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/road%20warrior) defines *road warrior* as:

> a person who travels a lot especially as part of his or her job
>
> a person who travels frequently especially on business

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word that describes the area to be covered. Ex: "District manager", "National salesperson", "International buyer".